# ListView Get Multiple Entry Values to validate and send

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I hope you can help me on this.

I have a survey from API, I want to display them in a ListView but my issue is, how can I validate each Entry from clicking a Send Button?

My CodeBehind

```
public class SurveyList
{
    public List<QuestionList> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionList
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class SurveyPage : ContentPage
{

    public SurveyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var surveyListData = new List<QuestionList>
        {
            new QuestionList { QuestionText = "Question 1?", QuestionCode = "01" },
            new QuestionList { QuestionText = "Question 2?", QuestionCode = "02" }
        };

        surveyList.ItemsSource = surveyListData;
    }

    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Button Clicked Get Values Here and Do Something
    }
}
```

}

My XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="surveyList"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
          BackgroundColor="White">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Purple">
                    <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                        <Label Text="{Binding QuestionLabel}" TextColor="Navy"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="QuestionPicker">
                            <Picker.Items>
                                <x:String>Yes</x:String>
                                <x:String>No</x:String>
                            </Picker.Items>
                        </Picker>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
                        <Button x:Name="surveyButton"
                                Text="Enviar"
                                TextColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource dpGreen}"
                                Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

With this code, I am testing out how to get all values from the clicked button

Comment: Not real for sure what your asking. But if your asking how to inspect each value of `SurveyListData` you can just do a Foreach and do whatever you need in the loop

Comment: hmm, let me try it out, foreach inside the button clicked method right? // Cannot access the list from the button clicked method, any other ideas?

Comment: @Andrew I did what you said and got each value, now how can I collect them all to send it via JSON?

Comment: There's many SO questions about serializing an object to JSON. A quick search will turn up many examples. If you still can't get your solution to work, please ask a separate question showing what you've tried. Also, now that you solved you original question, please add your answer here so anybody else searching can see it. It's perfectly ok to answer your own question.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew

Comment: Folloing thread go to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321427/serialize-listview-data-to-send-json-post)

Answer (score 1):

Using a Foreach as @Andrew said, solve the question.

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var getValues in survey)
        {
            getValuesOfPickers.Text = getValues.QuestionCode;
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it solve it completely, but as @Andrew said, the original question was answered