# Serialize ListView Data to send JSON POST

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following this question [ListView Get Multiple Entry Values to validate and send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319766/listview-get-multiple-entry-values-to-validate-and-send/52320882#52320882) I need now to serialize data to send it to the server, I've got this far:

```
public class SurveyList
{
    public List<QuestionList> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionList
{
    public string QuestionLabel { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class SurveyPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<QuestionList> survey;

    public SurveyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        survey = new List<QuestionList>
        {
            new QuestionList { QuestionLabel = "Question 1?", QuestionCode = "01" },
            new QuestionList { QuestionLabel = "Question 2?", QuestionCode = "02" }
        };

        surveyList.ItemsSource = survey;
    }

    void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myip");

        foreach (var getValues in survey)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> listViewData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Question", getValues.QuestionLabel },
                { "Answer", getValues.QuestionCode }
            };

            var listViewDataContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(listViewData);

            var response = client.PostAsync("/api/GetData", listViewDataContent);
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me get all the data correctly to be sent via POST. Not sure how to collect all data, since the data I am getting is dynamic.

Note: The data displayed there is static, but it should be getting the data from the same API

Thanks

Edit: Adding my Xaml Code

```
<ListView x:Name="surveyList"
      HasUnevenRows="true"
      SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
      BackgroundColor="White">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Purple">
                    <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                        <Label Text="{Binding QuestionLabel}" TextColor="Navy"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="QuestionPicker">
                            <Picker.Items>
                                <x:String>Yes</x:String>
                                <x:String>No</x:String>
                            </Picker.Items>
                        </Picker>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
                    <Button x:Name="surveyButton"
                            Text="Enviar"
                            TextColor="White"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource dpGreen}"
                            Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Button x:Name="surveyButton"
            Text="Send"
            TextColor="White"
            BackgroundColor="Teal"
            Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What format is the endpoint expecting? JSON?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?  Does it throw an error or exception?  What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I need it as JSON and I am using FormUrlEncodedContent

Comment: @Jason It does not do Anything at all :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to manually compose your Json there are other ways to do it.

First start by modifying your `QuestionList` object to have another field called `Answer` or however you prefer to call it.

```
public class QuestionList
{
    public string QuestionLabel { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

This new property will hold the value of the answer.

Second: Change your `List<QuestionList>` for an ObservableCollection

**Here:**

```
private ObservableCollection<QuestionList> survey;
```

**and here**

```
survey = new ObservableCollection<QuestionList>
{
    new QuestionList { QuestionLabel = "Question 1?", QuestionCode = "01" },
    new QuestionList { QuestionLabel = "Question 2?", QuestionCode = "02" }
};
```

Change a bit your XAML. Binding the `Answer` to the `Picker` `SelectedItem`. Here is where the "Magic" occurs.

```
<Picker x:Name="QuestionPicker" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding Answer, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Yes</x:String>
        <x:String>No</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Every time the user selects a value from the `Picker` it will be automatically update the `Answer` property of the List you set as the `ItemsSource`. More about Bindings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics)

Now you will just change the Button Clicked Event and with this line of code you will have a well done Json. (First you need to install [Newtonsoft Nugget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/))

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) a tutorial that shows how to install a nugget package (by coincidence they use this same library as example, lucky us!).

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey);
```

The above will create a json with the following format:

```
[
    {
        "QuestionLabel":"Question 1",
        "QuestionCode" : "01",
        "Answer":"No"
    },
    {
        "QuestionLabel":"Question 2",
        "QuestionCode" : "02",
        "Answer":"Yes"
    },
    {
        "QuestionLabel":"Question 3",
        "QuestionCode" : "03",
        "Answer":"Yes"
    },
    {
        "QuestionLabel":"Question 4",
        "QuestionCode" : "04",
        "Answer":"Yes"
    },
    {
        "QuestionLabel":"Question 5",
        "QuestionCode" : "05",
        "Answer":"No"
    }
]
```

As you can see this represents an Array of QuestionList and your server Endpoint should be expecting this as the request body. I filled the `Answer` with random values for clarity.

and the whole Click event code would look like

```
void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myip");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(survey);

        var listViewDataContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(json);
        var response = client.PostAsync("/api/GetData", listViewDataContent);
    }
}
```

Note: Notice I change a bit the way you initialize your HttpClient. Yeah I know [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) document exists but you are creating a new instance anyway on every click of the button and since this is not part of the question lest say we did not see it.

Note2: Match the values to what the server is expecting in the json. The important here was showing you that using the **Xamarin.Forms** Binding you could get the values out of the `ListView` and also that with **Newtownsoft.Json** you could easily convert your data from a **C#** Object to **Json**. More about this library [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thank you very much @apineda I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I solve it, thanks to @apineda and @Andrew, who guided me to the right direction. Maybe the solution is not as clean as it can be, but it works.

Step 1 - The Model

I have two classes in it

- SurveyList
- QuestionList

  ```
  public class SurveyList
  {
      [JsonProperty("title")]
      public string SurveyTtitle { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("questions")]
      public List<QuestionList> Questions { get; set; }
  }

  public class QuestionList
  {
      [JsonProperty("question")]
      public string QuestionText { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("questionId")]
      public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Step 2 - My Xaml

- My ListView Header for the Title

  ```
  <ListView.Header>
      <StackLayout Padding="0, 30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <Label x:Name="surveyTitle" Text="" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      </StackLayout>
  </ListView.Header>
  ```
- The ListView ItemTemplate

  ```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Padding="5, 5, 5, 15" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                  <Label Text="{Binding QuestionText}"/>
                  <Picker ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding QuestionCode}" Title="Select Yes or No" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray" SelectedIndexChanged="Handle_SelectedIndexChanged">
                      <Picker.Items>
                          <x:String>Yes</x:String>
                          <x:String>No</x:String>
                      </Picker.Items>
                  </Picker>
              </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  ```
- ListView Footer for the Button To Send Data

  ```
  <ListView.Footer>
      <StackLayout Padding="0, 30, 0, 30">
          <Button x:Name="surveyButton"
                  Text="Send Survey"
                  TextColor="White"
                  BackgroundColor="Teal"
                  Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ListView.Footer>
  ```

Step 3 - My CodeBehind

I added parameters, a IDictionary, the baseURI, the API and the resource

```
    private IDictionary<string, string> Answers;
    private string baseUri = "http://myip";
    private string api = "/api";
    private string resource = "/GetData";
    private string username = "username";
    private string password = "password";
```

Inside the constructor I instantiate the Dictionary Object

```
    Answers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Added an override OnAppearing() so each time the page is called it calls the API and check if they are surveys available (Note: @apineda, sorry, did not added your code, which is cleaner, but I was already coding it)

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/json"));

        var response = client.GetAsync(api).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var getJson = client.GetStringAsync(api + resource).Result;
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyList>(getJson);

            surveyTitle.Text = jsonString.SurveyTtitle;
            Survey = new List<QuestionList>();

                foreach (var surveys in jsonString.Questions)
                {
                    Survey.Add(new QuestionList { QuestionText = surveys.QuestionText, QuestionCode = surveys.QuestionCode });
                }

                surveyList.ItemsSource = Survey;
                surveyList.EndRefresh();

                stackButton.IsVisible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            surveyTitle.Text = "No Surveys Available";
        }
```

Pickers Selected Index Change to add values to the Answers Dictionary every time it changes

```
    void Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        var picker = sender as Picker;

        var item = picker.BindingContext;

        var question = item as QuestionList;

        Answers.Add(question.QuestionCode, picker.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Button Method to send all data

```
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Answers)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> collectAnswers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                 { item.Key, item.Value }
            };
        }
         var collectAnswersContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collectAnswers);

         var response = await client.PostAsync(api + "/addSurveyAnswers", collectAnswersContent);

         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             await DisplayAlert(null, "Thank you for answering the survey", "Close");
             (sender as Button).BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00afb9");

         }
         else
         {
             await DisplayAlert("Error", "Please Try Again, something went wrong", "OK");
             (sender as Button).BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00afb9");
         }
    }
```

I know this code is not so clean (newbie at Xamarin and C#), just wanted to post the answer in case someone may finds it useful. I am violating the programmers law, I am repeating myself in many places, but it works so far and now I can start cleaning the code

Thanks again to everyone!!!
Happy Coding